# Need PHP code to store a JSONArray from android into a remote database

Tags: php, android, json, android-json

My aim is to add the contents of the local database onto a remote database.
I am adding the contents of the database as a custom object into a JSONArray.
I am converting this JSONArray as string and Passing this string as POST parameter to the php page,but i am unable to write the php code to store this content in the database on the serverside.
Pls help me to write the PHP Code

Getting the data from the data base and storing into JSONArray

```
DataEntry d=new DataEntry(context);
JSONArray call_records=d.get();
String update_content=call_records.toString();
success= new GetUpdateStatus().execute(update_content).get();
```

get() method of DataEntry class

```
public JSONArray get() throws JSONException
    {   
        JSONArray CallList = new JSONArray();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE +";";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
                CallRecord record = new CallRecord();
                record.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                record.setCaller(cursor.getString(1));
                record.setReciever(cursor.getString(2));
                record.setMapUrl(cursor.getString(3));
                record.setTimeStamp(String.valueOf((cursor.getType(4))));


                CallList.put(record.getJSONObject());

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return CallList;
    }
```

CallRecord class:

```
public class CallRecord {
    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _caller;
    String _reciever;
    String _map;
    String _ts;
//This class has set and get methods for each variable.
}
```

The JSON Parser Code:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(String... a) {
        int success=0;
        try {         
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("add",a[0]));
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                               url_update, "POST", params);
```

and this:

```
if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to get the raw POST data.

`$post = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Answer (score 0):

using this you will get all post data as array in $data variable.

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);